# CSS- Expanding An Element Without Losing Page's Original Structure. To create Drop Down

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index

I want to create a drop down menu (alternate to Browser's `<select>` tag).

So Here I've created a `<div>` in another `<div>` to stimulate the `<select>`

But When I expand the dropdown `<div>` The Exapanded `div` Pushes down all other page's structure.

I mean, Here is **output of my actual code**: 
[image: Initial]

**Clicking on Expand** Produces:
[image: OnClick]

But **I want Output** Something Like :
[image: Expected]

I tried adding `float:left`, `z-index`, `position:absolute;` etc. But No Luck.

Here is My Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Drop Down Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
.ddown{
        width:250px;
        background: #aaa;
        border: 2px solid #777;
        color: #444;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px;
        display: inline-block;
    z-index:5;
    float:left;
    overflow:visible;
    }
    .ddown a{
        width: 100%;
        height: 25px;
        text-align: left;
        color: #666;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #ddd;
        border: 1px solid #999;
    z-index:5;
    display:none;

    }
    .ddownHead{
        display: inline-block !important;
    }
    .ddownItem{
        display: inline-block !important;
        z-index:5;!important
    }
    .ddownItem:hover{
        background: #33a;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .ddown_busy{
        background: #77a !important;
        border: 1px solid #558 !important;
        color: #fff !important;
    }
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_expand_ddown(x){
        if($(x).closest("div").find("a").eq(0).hasClass("ddown_busy")){
            $(x).closest("div").find("a").eq(0).removeClass("ddown_busy");
        $(x).closest("div").find("div").each(function(){
            $(this).find("a").each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("ddownItem");
            });
        });
        }
        else
        {
        $(x).closest("div").find("a").eq(0).addClass("ddown_busy");
        $(x).closest("div").find("div").each(function(){
            $(this).find("a").each(function(){
                $(this).addClass("ddownItem");
            });
        });
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="width:100%;height:auto;background:#aa0;border:2px solid #770;z-index:10;">
    <div class="ddown">
    <a class="ddownHead" href="#!" Onclick="toggle_expand_ddown(this);">Click to Expand</a>
    <div style="z-index:6;">
        <a href="#!">Item 1</a>
        <a href="#!">Item 1</a>
        <a href="#!">Item 1</a>
        <a href="#!">Item 1</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    This is Another Child in same Parent
</div>
<div style="background:#eee;color:#555;width:100%;height:200px;display:inline-block;z-index:2;box-shadow:10px 10px 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);border:2px solid #555;border-radius:12px;text-align:center;margin:5px;position:absolute;">Heya</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And Here is The: [`***Fiddle***`](http://jsfiddle.net/Smith_jones_1111/FuhgN/4/)

Hope Experts Here Will Help Me. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added only `position:absolute` in your class and it works

```
.ddown{
        width:250px;
        background: #aaa;
        border: 2px solid #777;
        color: #444;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px;
        display: inline-block;
    z-index:5;
    float:left;
    overflow:visible;
    position: absolute;
    }
```

**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/FuhgN/5/)** the updated fiddle

Comment: How silly I am. Thanks For Quick Reply. It Worked like Charm.

Comment: I realize now that my fiddle doesn't work but the code I wrote it's right ;) btw, your welcome

Answer (score 1):

You could just apply `position: absolute` to `.ddown`

```
.ddown{
    width:250px;
    background: #aaa;
    border: 2px solid #777;
    color: #444;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index:5;
    float:left;
    overflow:visible;
    position: absolute;
}
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/FuhgN/6/

Comment: How silly I am. Thanks For Quick Reply. I Love SO! So Many Great and Helpful Programmers are Here. But I'll Not accept your answer coz Your Reputation is already High! +1 For your Answer and Will accept @dborghez's Answer. Anyways Really Really Thank you so much.