# Dropdown is coming down of the downside image

Tags: html, css

I have two div with background images.In the first one i have dropdown menu and second one is simply background image.The problem that i am facing is with Dropdown menu and second background image,the dropdown is coming inside the backgorund image and i am not able to figure out as how to resolve it..

Here is the CSS that i have used for both the div..

```
 //first Div
.header-wrapper {
background: url("../images/header_bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
float: left;
height: 77px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 60001; }

 //second div
.headerbody-wrapper {
background: url("../images/bill.jpg");
float: left;
margin-top: 77px;
height: 242px;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 60001; }
```

Here is the HTML..

```
 <div class="header-wrapper">
 </div>
 <div class="headerbody-wrapper">
         <p>hello</p>

    </div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R2yNW/)

My About US dropdown is coming inside to the second div image and i want to remove it..

Comment: Add `jsfiddle` demo please. It will be solved quicker or at least add HTML part.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308383/css-expanding-an-element-without-losing-pages-original-structure-to-create-dr

Comment: @Siyah Wait i will update the post

Comment: @SiyahI have added the HTML

Comment: It goes under? http://jsfiddle.net/6zgqy/ Is that what you want?

Comment: @VedantTerkar Position abosolute is not working..

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev I have dropdown in my first div but the contents of the dropdown is coming inside of the second div image

Comment: @user3664608 Post `JavaScript` part please.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Wait I am trying to make fiddle..

Comment: @user3664608 a `jsfiddle` would make your logic more clear.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Please see my updated post with Fidlle.

Comment: @user3664608 is that what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/R2yNW/1/

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Nope Actually My About US dropdown is coming inside the second div image while it should be shown above the image..That is the problem with the CSS rest of the things are fine

Comment: @user3664608 Why don't you possibly try to consider using Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/) and not to re-create bicycle once again? Unfortunately can't help you out as I don't understand what you're trying to do. Have a good luck with this.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev AboutUS is a dropdown menu that responds on Mousehover and this is in First Div.Now as soon as i am hovering on AboutUs its contents is getting hidden inside the second div background image..And i want to remove that one only...Please help..

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Is this because of position property or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution ..It was to change `position: fixed;` to `position: inherit;`

Its Working...!!

Answer (score 0):

It's a **position** and **z-index** problem, you can add this:

```
.header nav{
     position:relative;
     z-index: 60003; 
}

.header nav li > ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}
```

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R2yNW/2/)